# How to create a class (not a classifier) with a variable in IBM Watson Visual Recognition with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I'm trying to create a new class with the API like it's shown in the API Documentation https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition?code=python#update-a-classifier

The part that Watson uses as the name of the class is the prefix of "_positive_examples". I need to use the content of a variable as the prefix, but it's a keyword and I can't add any variable there (variableNotWorking in the code).

I have tried to format as a string and also to create a dictionary in Python and introduce it there but I always obtain an error either from Python or Watson.

```
    positive = nuevaClase + '_positive_examples'
    visual_recognition = credencials()
    with open(aprDirFitxer1, 'rb') as nuevaClase:
            updated_model = visual_recognition.update_classifier(
                classifier_id=classifId,
                positive_examples={positive : nuevaClase}).get_result()
```

The error from Watson that I always obtain is:

```
watson_developer_cloud.watson_service.WatsonApiException: Error: Cannot execute learning task.  Did not find any files to process in the POST request body. , Code: 400
```

Comment: Which version of the Watson Python SDK are you using? A new version was released recently that uses a different format to specify the classifiers so it's important to know which version you are using.

Comment: The version is VisualRecognitionV3

Comment: I updated it to the new format but I always obtain the same response: watson_developer_cloud.watson_service.WatsonApiException: Error: Cannot execute learning task.  Did not find any files to process in the POST request body. , Code: 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem may be that you are using an old version of the SDK because the package name changed in Version 3 to "ibm-watson". You need to install the new SDK package with

```
pip install --upgrade ibm-watson
```

and then in your Python code, import from this new package:

```
from ibm_watson import VisualRecognitionV3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. How can I know or where can I find if a package name changes or if I have to update? I'm using now the services: Assistant, VisualRecognition, SpeechToText and TextToSpeech.